# How large can the set $\partial ( \bigcup_i B_i ) \setminus \bigcup_i ( \partial B_i )$ be, where the $B_i$ are open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Suppose that $$E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i,$$ where the $B_i$ are open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for $i\ne j$, $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$.

We know that generally $$\bigcup_i \partial B_i \subsetneq \partial E.$$ For example if $E$ is bounded, and if $x_k$ are the centers of the balls $B_k$, then $\{x_k\}$ have a cluster point $x_0$. It's not hard to see that $x_0 \in \partial E$, however generically, $x_0$ can be not in any $\partial B_i$.

My my question is, how large is the set $\partial E \setminus \bigcup_i \partial B_i$?

I guess it should be countable. If not, $$\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial E \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_i} \partial B_i)=0$$should be true, where $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ denotes the $(n{-}1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

I cannot even prove the weak claim. Maybe I missed something, or there are examples to show the claims are false? Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not be countable. You could have a tree arrangement of balls, with increasingly smaller radius. Whose limit could for example be the cantor set.

Comment: Thanks! I later realized that. Now what puzzled me is about the dimension of the set. Can I say the dimension is less than n-1?

Comment: @student It sounds intuitive, but of course that means nothing these days. The boundary will be nowhere dense so do you have examples of dimension $n$ nowhere dense sets ? If so you can try to realize them an boundaries.

Comment: Yes, there are nowhere dense sets which have positive measure. These sets can be realized as the complement of disjoint balls centered at diadic points.  So the dimension of $\partial E \setminus \cup_i(\partial B_i)$ can be $n$.  Thanks!